# Exported image not rendering correctly in iOS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, iphone

I have this image in .ai format and I exported it out as png of sizes: 25x25, 50x50 and 75x75 pngs for iOS tab bar icon.

[image: 25]
[image: 50]
[image: 75]

But when it renders in iPhone, I see this (the first icon - looks like an egg):

[image: tab bar]

So what is the issue here? Pixels too dense in the original illustration? Not a graphic designer so please help me understand how can I fix it.

Comment: If you just view the 25x25 image, does it look correct? If so, then it's probably an error in the code.

Comment: Yes, it looks correct (added it to the question). I dont think its an issue in code because its ios default behavior and I don't have a custom tab bar. Other icons (like trophy) renders fine.

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with file naming or other non-image pixel specific related issue.

Comment: In Illustrator, did you create the white and light green parts with actual white and light green shapes, or are they (partially) transparent, with Illustrator's artboard providing the white?

Comment: @Vincent I don't know, a freelancer did it.

Comment: Then try and confirm that--if you can export from Illustrator, you can sure check the shapes and opacities, right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894974/how-can-i-fix-the-tab-bar-of-the-tab-bar-controller-in-ios

> The problem is that your image lacks transparency. The tab bar expects
>   your image to be a *transparency mask* (also called a template) - only
>   its degree of transparency / opacity is taken into account. Your image
>   is completely solid opaque, so it appears as a solid square.
>
> Either fix your image, or derive from it an image whose rendering mode
>   is Always Original to force that actual drawing of the image to appear
>   instead of its opacity.

Also the tab bar images should be of only 1 color. This is the final image which works:

[image: working logo]

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html